How can I get Scipy stats median_test to return object and not tuple?
I've got a script that should return a MedianTestResult object with statistic, median, and pvalue attributes, but instead I get an unlabeled tuple. Not sure what each element in the tuple corresponds to. I would prefer to get the labeled object.
I tried this:
res1 = median_test(HCVs, genpops, nan_policy = 'omit')
print(res1.median)
where HCVs and genpops were lists of floats.
Based on the Scipy documentation, I expected the second line to print a float-valued median of the entire sample; however, the result returned "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'median'". Is there some way to get the labels for each element in the list?

TLDR: Upgrade SciPy.

To fix this problem, simply upgrade to the latest version of SciPy. As documented in the 1.10.0 release notes, the value returned  by median_test was changed from a regular tuple to a "bunch" in that release, so any version 1.10.0 or later will do. Your version of SciPy is simply too old to have that feature.
If you don't want to upgrade, create a namedtuple with the fields in the order listed in the documentation, and instantiate it with the (unpacked) tuple returned by median_test.
from collections import namedtuple
from scipy.stats import median_test

g1 = [10, 14, 14, 18, 20, 22, 24, 25, 31, 31, 32, 39, 43, 43, 48, 49]
g2 = [28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40, 44, 55, 57, 61, 91, 92, 99]
g3 = [0, 3, 9, 22, 23, 25, 25, 33, 34, 34, 40, 45, 46, 48, 62, 67, 84]
res = median_test(g1, g2, g3)

MedianTestResult = namedtuple('MedianTestResult', ['statistic', 'pvalue', 'median', 'table'])
res = MedianTestResult(*res)
res.median  # 34.0


When I try to pip install --upgrade spicy, I get the following, which I think indicates I have a recent enough version:
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.27.0,>=1.19.5 in
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scipy) (1.24.3)
Is there anything else I can try?

Yes. pip install scipy==1.13.0. The package name is "scipy", not "spicy". Beyond that, uninstall and reinstall, create a new virtual environment and reinstall everything, or try installing the Anaconda distribution of Python and using conda. Beyond that, open a new question on Stack Overflow. Your original question has been answered, and this is a different question.
